# Update PHP with javascript trigger and MySQL backend

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to create a thumbnail carousel on my page. It loads 6 images with links from a sql database. When you click the next button it will go down the list of the 6 images selecting with a border the current one the page is on. When you are on image 6 and click next, I want it to load the next 6 in descending order from the mysql database. I can't seem to do this. I currently have this setup.

--Connect and select from database

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx");
mysql_select_db("xxxx");
$result = mysql_query("select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from `images` WHERE `id` ORDER BY     id DESC LIMIT 6");

$row_object = mysql_query("Select Found_Rows() as rowcount");
$row_object = mysql_fetch_object($row_object);
$actual_row_count = $row_object->rowcount;
```

and this is the code in the carousel which is working

```
<div id="thumbs-top" class="jcarousel">
<ul id="thumbs-data" class="thumbs-grid">
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo              '<li><a href="########'.$row['filename'].'.html">';
echo                '<img class="thumb-title"       src="http://dknwp6sl3x0i8.cloudfront.net/thumbs/'.$row['filename'].'.jpg" title="###   ###<p>441 points : 185,038 views</p>" />';
echo                '</a></li>';            
}
?>          
</ul>
```

now I have it setup so if the url matches the href in the unordered list, it adds the class selected which makes a border around the thumbnail.

Too load the next 6 thumbnail images from the database I have it setup so if there is no "selected" class in the ul then I load a php script to post the next 6 but I cannot get that to work

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
if (!$('ul.thumbs-grid li a img').hasClass('thumb-title selected')) 
{
$('#thumbs-data').load('data.php');
}
});
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to work. It creates a mysql fetch array error.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

I want the ul in the "data.php" to overwrite the current data loaded in the carousel.

Is there any other way to fix or do this? I'm fairly new to coding so please bear with me

Site I am having the trouble on - http://vine.youlawl.com/

Comment: What error ? Post error log as well. You need to pass some identifier value to php that will identify which rows to be fetched next (like ID for something. Ex rows having ID > 6, ID > 12 etc).

Comment: Warning:  mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource  Is the way I have this setup the right way to do something like this?

Comment: Consider using PDO statements or MySQLi. `mysql_` functions are deprecated and your script will be really susceptible to SQL injections.